# SOLR on a hosted server

Tags: solr

Is it possible to move solr to a hosted server? (in general is it possible to install SOLR on a web hosting service like bluehost.com or godaddy.com ? )

I have worked a bit on Solr and am currently running a SOLR server using JETTY on one of my local machines.

I saw a few articles on the net which speak about setting it up on Amazon EC2, but i could not find anything related to setting up solr on a hosted server.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run a java application on your shared hosting you can run solr.

Comment: Thanks Shashwat. I think I have to follow the steps mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350529/how-to-run-a-java-program-on-a-server to check if I can run java applications. I will try to check it tonight. Assuming I can, could you give me a few hints or pointers on how to run SOLR ?